# How to Loop in google appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I have this script that will check if Column B last row in Main Tab is Blank, If blank it will get the value from Backend Tab E2 and set it on the last row Column A Main Tab.

How do I make it loop itself every 3 mins if the conditions are not met and also how do I make it select not only on Backend!E2 but from Backend!E2:E11 incrementing every 3 mins if the conditions are not met.

Condition : Column B last row is blank in Main Tab.

Script:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const liveSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Main');
  const assigned = e.source.getRange('Backend!E2').getDisplayValue();
  const response = e.range.getValues();
  liveSheet.appendRow([assigned, null, null, null, null, null, ...response[0]]);

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var MainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
var Emplist = ss.getSheetByName("Backend");
var lastRow = MainSheet.getLastRow();
var data = MainSheet.getRange(lastRow, 2, 1, 1).getValue();

 if (data == "") {

  var setValue = Emplist.getRange(2, 5, 1, 1).getValue();
  MainSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 1).setValue(setValue);

}
}
```

SpreadSheet [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZCcwAM7BQwGY_7YqcasjE8HSNrJUEJ3Onf5XAmTlax4/edit#gid=626846405)
if you guys need a sample. It is basically a Ticketing system where it runs on google form submission

I tried the for loop but I cant get it loop until the conditions are met

Comment: You changed the code and by the way for an onformsubmit for a spreadsheet you don't need get the data from the linked sheet it's already loaded into the triggers event object.  Just do a submit and use `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));`

Comment: If you want something to happen every 3 minutes try a time based trigger

Comment: Yes. Sorry for changing the code. Want I want to happen is if a user submits a form it will assign an employee on Column A. So if the employee does not respond (by inputting something on the Status, Column B) in 3 minutes it will automatically replace the name of the employee (from Backend!E2).

Comment: My advice would be to leave the linked sheet alone in case you ever need the data and do all of your custom work on another sheet and capture the data from the onFormSubmit.   I would still use a time based trigger for accomplishing your desires but I don't wish to write the code for you unless you have a specific problem please try to do you own work.

Comment: Okay Thanks Cooper. I will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function lfunko() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var msh = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
  var esh = ss.getSheetByName("Backend");
  var lastRow = msh.getLastRow();
  var data = msh.getRange(lastRow, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
  if (data == "") {
    msh.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 1).setValue(esh.getRange(2, 5, 1, 1).getValue());
  }
}

function createTimeBasedTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "lfunko").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("lfunko").timeBased().everyMinutes(3).create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Im sorry I did not add the whole Script I used. I updated my script up top. Can you please look at it again? Thank you.